# Is it poor etiquette to post here + at Apple Support Communities?

Tags: support

Is it frowned on to post the same thing here and at Apple Support Communities?

If it's not, should I cross list the questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We only ask that one Stack Exchange site contain your question. As long as you are the author and not simply copying someone else's question I see no reason why anyone would object to you posting here your question if it's on an external site.

Comment: Should I cross list the question on here and at Apple Support Communities?

Comment: Your call. I can't speak for Apple, but my experience is each has a slightly different group that answers, so you might want to craft the basic question differently here versus there. There's no need to cross link them unless one site has some breakthrough that you'd like to share on the other.

Comment: I would probably not cross list as the question and answers here should be self sufficient and not rely on external links. Links can give more info on answers but not be required to understand the issue